# How to get the rows that is in the same week?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, group-by

I have a database and a date column in the database which has values like 5/2/2012 vs. I am trying to get all the rows that is in the same week and count each week how man row it has.
I try to get an output like the below:

For example

```
8-14 October  |  15
1-7 October   |  8
24-30 September | 12
etc...
```

I will probably use group by and count statement and functions but ı have no idea how to detect a week like 8-14 October.

The database is a maximo database by oracle. Thanks.

Comment: which RDBMS ? mysql or sql server?

Comment: Sorry, it's an oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trunc(date_value) will return first day of week (sunday):

```
select 
    trunc(date_column,'D') as start_date, 
    trunc(date_column,'D')+6 end_date, 
    count(*)
from your_table
group by trunc(date_column,'D')
```